# Multi-environment config issue

Tags: config, database, multi-environment, environments

I'm trying to set up Craft and on deployment to a staging server am getting the following error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Craft can't connect to the database with the credentials in
>   craft/config/db.php.") in "_layout" at line 39.

The config file in question is posted up at https://gist.github.com/cole007/f32c7ba984a3d35b1d24

Any thoughts?

Cheers in advance,

Cole

Comment: As far as I can see your config looks absolutely fine... could it simply be a DB credential issue for that particular environment?

Answer (score 1):

Sorted, thanks. The keen-eyed of you will notice that there was a space character in the server connection details. Idiot

Comment: I'd also suggest you remove the real DB name in future too... :)